# Flipper Error: Failed while retrieving marketplace plugins SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, macos, flipper

I am working on a React Native App and using Flipper for debugging.  Flipper will not consistently stay connected to my application.  I thought it had something to do with a miss-patch of Flipper versions in the Podfile.  Fixing the version miss-match worked for a short time.

I have a single error now:
`Failed while retrieving marketplace plugins SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

I understand the error.  But, I can't track it down, since there is no stack-trace!

Comment: Are you using any API ?

Answer (score -1):

The Cause
This happens when you make a request to the server and parse the response as JSON, but it’s not JSON. The code responsible might look something like this:

```
fetch('/users').then(res => res.json())
```

The actual request worked fine. It got a response. But the res.json() is what failed.

Comment: are you frm dubai @Iva?